# Masking image on Shape

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs3

I have a photo, and on it, I have drawn a circle with a shape.

I want to make it so that only the parts of the photo that are within this circle are visible, and what is outside the circle should not be visible. Therefore, I should be able to position the image with part of it in the circle and end up with an image that is the shape of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layer -> New Clipping Mask

Place image above the shape and apply the above.